# Symfony - links from microsoft excel redirect to login page

Tags: excel, symfony

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a column that contain links to my page under auth in a symfony 3.4 project.

Each link opened from Excel is redirected to login page even if I am already logged in.

Copy and paste the link in browser, obviously, works.
If I click the link from the same file but using LibreOffice it works.
It's something related to the firewall, for sure but what?
This is my firewall config:

```
firewalls:
dev:
  pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
  security: false
  form_login:
    always_use_default_target_path: false
    default_target_path: /backend
    target_path_parameter: _target_path
    use_referer: true
statics:
  pattern: ^/(css|images|js)/
  security: false

main:
  pattern: ^/
  form_login:
    use_referer: true
    provider: fos_userbundle
    csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
    success_handler: login_success_handler
    failure_handler: login_failure_handler
  logout:
    path: /logout
    target: /
    handler: logout_listener
  anonymous: true
  switch_user:
    role: ROLE_ADMIN
  remember_me:
    secret: "%secret%"
    lifetime: 31536000 
    path: /
```

My urls are simply http or https url to my site http://MYDOMAIN/backend/etcetc.
No errors in log.

I've no idea...
Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't think I can help without further input. For example, what is the url format? How is your firewall configured? Do you see any errors in your logs?

Comment: Sorry, I added the required details to the main question.

Comment: Does the url contain a special character? Maybe the path must be urlencoded?

Comment: No special chars in the url. Maybe it's a security feature and it's no possible to do it

Comment: It can't be problem with Excel or firewall if your URL works after copy/paste. Do this scenario: **1.** Copy paste link to browser **2.** Click on URL from Excel spreadsheer **3.** Check Symfony profiler "Reuest / Response" tab for latest requests and provide screenshot for us